# C++ wait for a callback to complete within a callback

Tags: c++, c++11

We have a code that registers a callback. So the flow that registers the callback has no knowledge of when the callback will be called.

Now the callback will called by another flow in a thread - hence the main flow that has registered the callback needs to wait for callback to complete.

I am having no idea to implement the same as I cannot modify anything in the other thread that will call the callback. How can I make my main thread to responds synchronously - after the callback is called by other thread?

Comment: show the code please.
Are you using any library for managing callbacks?

Comment: No we are not using a library for callback - I do not have any code to show as the same is proprietary - sorry for same - but is there a design solution if any?

Comment: The question is not completely clear to me, but maybe you are searching for mutex? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion

Comment: The mutex will make the main flow to wait until the callback is called - can we avoid this wait period

Comment: As an answer to your comment, maybe you can set the mutex  in your callback. From this side your problem is not clear enough IMHO... But  maybe you already got a better answer from @comicsansms

Comment: That last statement of yours makes it even less clear what you want. Please do some research, starting with a mutex and going to the other utilities that C++ provides for multithreaded programming. I'm halfway sure you will find something suitable or at least be able to explain better what it is that you want to achieve. Concerning code you can't show, you could still extract something similar to a [mcve], nobody wants the whole code here.

Comment: Do not try to use mutex to wait for stuff. At least with C++11's `std::mutex` it is not possible to implement signalling reliably (it might happen to work on some platforms, but it won't be portable). Rule of thumb in C++11: `mutex` = preventing concurrent access, `condition_variable` = wait for stuff. Of course these are only the lowest-level primitives, so using a better abstraction like `future` or `packaged_task` is often advisable.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to share *some* state between the two that can be used to communicate this.

As a corollary, if the callback is stateless, this cannot be done (or only within certain restrictions, such as limiting the number of callbacks that can be active at the same time).

Since the access to that shared state potentially happens concurrently from different threads, all access needs to be synchronized, ie. made thread-safe.

Here is a simple example using `std::future`:

```
#include <future>
// [...]

std::promise<void> p;
do_work_async([&p]() { p.set_value(); });

std::future<void> f = p.get_future();
f.get();  // this line will block until the callback is executed
```

Note that this has potential lifetime issues: The promise needs to be kept alive until the callback has executed. Depending on your program, this might make it necessary to put the promise on the heap.

If stateless callbacks are not supported (eg. the callback parameter must be a plain C-function pointer and no injection point for user state is provided) you need to put your shared state into `static` storage instead, with the usual resulting limitations.

Comment: Thanks can you please explain regarding your point on C-function pointer approach?

Comment: @Programmer A lambda can only be bound to a C function pointer if its capture list is empty. Similarly, you cannot bind a class member function to a C function pointer. Therefore, if you want to make such a callback stateful, the callback signature needs to allow passing in arbitrary userdata as a parameter. That is why asnc C APIs usually give a `void*` parameter to such callbacks that is controlled by the user.